# PSQL - how to insert data to the altered table?

Tags: sql, insert, alter-table

I have an `EMPLOYEE` table with foreign key `Dno` that refers to `Dnumber` in the `DEPARTMENT` table. In the `DEPARTMENT` table there is also foreign key `Mgr_ssn` that refers to `Ssn` in `EMPLOYEE` table.

I created the table using

```
ALTER TABLE employee 
ADD foreign key (dno) references department(dnumber) 
    on delete restrict on update cascade;
```

(both Dno and Mgr_ssn are NOT NULL)

But now I am confused how to insert the data, because it always violates referential integrity constraint, any suggestion?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys are usually not given the "not null" constraint. What would you do if there is a new employee who has not been assigned a dept. Or a new dept with no manager.

Still, for your problem you should use the "**DEFERRABLE**" property of Oracle Constraints. This means, any constraint will be checked at commit point only. Thus you can insert dno and empnos first, commit later. At this point there will be no constraint viokation as the FK exists.

`ALTER TABLE employee 
ADD foreign key (dno) references department(dnumber) 
INITIALLY DEFERRED DEFERRABLE;`

--Do the Same for dept

Then,

`Insert into emp (...)
insert into dept(...)
commit;`